# Uniswap WETH_WBTC price is orders of magnitude off when using constant product market maker formula

Tags: web3js, tokens, uniswap, bignumber, amm

I am trying to calculate the value of an exchange on Uniswap using Web3js and methods from the Uniswap smart contract.

*This is the Uniswap contract address for the WETH (Wrapped Ether) : WBTC (Wrapped Bitcoin) pair*
*0xBb2b8038a1640196FbE3e38816F3e67Cba72D940*

Using that contract address and the contract ABI I construct a js-object for the contract like this: `const pairContract = new web3.eth.Contract(pair.abi, pair.address);`

This works fine and I am able to read the contract methods as well as call methods on the contract (I'm only using read-only methods - I don't need to sign any transactions). So I am able to call the `getReserves` method like this

```
const reserves = await pairContract.methods.getReserves().call();
```

And here is the response (at this `_blockTimestampLast`)

```
{
  '0': '296352466321',
  '1': '37712426843492788602200',
  '2': '1621116220',
  _reserve0: '296352466321',
  _reserve1: '37712426843492788602200',
  _blockTimestampLast: '1621116220'
}
```

`_reserve0` are the WBTC reserves and `_reserve1` are the WETH reserves

**Now here in this implementation is where somehow things are going wrong...**

```
const BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');

const estimateTrade = (
  baseTokenReserves, 
  quoteTokenReserves, 
  numberOfBaseTokenTradedIn, 
  feePercent)=> {

        // x * y = k
 
        const feeMultiplier = BigNumber(1).minus(feePercent.dividedBy(100));

        const k = baseTokenReserves.times(quoteTokenReserves);

        const baseTokenNewTotal = baseTokenReserves.plus(numberOfBaseTokenTradedIn.times(feeMultiplier));

        const quoteTokenNewTotal = k.dividedBy(baseTokenNewTotal);

        const quoteTokenReceived = quoteTokenReserves.minus(quoteTokenNewTotal);

        return quoteTokenReceived;

}
```

Calling my `estimatedTrade` method with these arguments...

```
const baseTokenReserves = BigNumber(_reserve0);
const quoteTokenReserves = BigNumber(_reserve1);
const numberOfBaseTokenTradedIn = BigNumber(1);
const feePercent = BigNumber(0.03);

const tokensReceived = estimateTrade(baseTokensReserves, quoteTokenReserves, numberOfBaseTokenTradedIn , feePercent)

console.log(`tokensReceived = ${tokensReceived.toFixed()}`) //tokensReceived = 127151098781.56376683928985070517
```

This obviously is way off. When I check on Uniswap to see how many WETH I would get for 1 WBTC I see roughly `12.677`. I've checked for hours and every time my answer is off by 10 decimal places (10,000,000,000 times). This method works well for every other pair I've tried (WETH_SUSHI, WETH_UNI, etc.) except for WETH_WBTC. Can anyone see what the issue is? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a similar issue when looking at USDC and WETH and using ethers.js . This is how I was originally converting my Big Numbers:

```
const reserve0 = Number(ethers.utils.formatUnits(reserves[0], 18)); //USDC
const reserve1 = Number(ethers.utils.formatUnits(reserves[1], 18)); //WETH
```

I figured out that the issue was that USDC only uses 6 decimal places, not 18. So I had to change it to this:

```
const reserve0 = Number(ethers.utils.formatUnits(reserves[0], 6)); //USDC
const reserve1 = Number(ethers.utils.formatUnits(reserves[1], 18)); //WETH
```

Based on the WBTC contract on etherscan, WBTC uses 8 decimals, so I would guess that is your problem.